# RecyclerView Class android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable can not be found

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using RecyclerView on my app, but at runtime app crashes and my logcat reads:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclertest/com.example.recyclertest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.recyclertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.recyclertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.a

ndroid.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/recyclerview/R$styleable;
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:434)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:404)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.recyclertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.recyclertest-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:434)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.<init>(RecyclerView.java:404)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.recyclertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.recyclerview.R$styleable
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 27 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I added android-support-v7-cardview, android-support-v7-gridlayout,
android-support-v7-recyclerview and android-support-v7-appcompat
to my project.
I'm using intellij idea

a on API Level 22

Comment: I'm not familiar with intellji, but your issue seem to because you only added the jar file of those project. Please check and add them as dependencies module. Maybe this link will help you https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html

Comment: I added them to dependencies too and not working... when I open android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar the recyclerview folder is empty and the error points to "/recyclerview/R$styleable" that's missing, why is that?

Answer (score 7):

You need to clear recyclerview lib project and build it again. Then build your app. Now class must be found.

Comment: @ANinJa it would be better if you stopped using Eclipse and started using Android Studio. In Android Studio is easy to manage external libs instead of Eclipse

Comment: but what about the companies who is running their projects since 2-3 year in eclipse, in future will google shutdown all the eclipse support ?

Comment: @ANinJa I think that Google will still support developers tools for Eclipse and others, but convert project to Android Studio is not hard. Our company had some old projects, and I success convert them to Android Studio. It takes about 1 working day per project

Comment: What do you mean by `clear recyclerview lib`?It's just a `android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar` lib.

Comment: @zionpi, my answer applicable only when you use Eclipse for developing. If you are using Android Studio try to press Build -> Clear Project and then Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 4):

I am still using Eclipse, not Intellij, but it might help you, as I stumbled across this very error today after upgrading to the latest version of the support library.
I used to just have the recyclerview jar copied into my project;s lib folder and added to dependencies. Apparently this was not the right way anymore. I had to re-add the library as "library with resources" - pretty much the same way as the cardview library needs to be added.

For Eclipse I just followed the instructions at https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html from the "Adding libraries with resources" section. FWIW I had to mark the newly added recyclerview as being a library during the import process (the default is not and this step was skipped in the instructions).

I hope it helps!

Comment: In the documentation they don't speak about Eclipse user....can you explain how you add library with resource in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I also got a similar error a while back.
Make sure that you are not using

```
<RecyclerView>
```

tag as it is in your code, and using

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and that your build.gradle file has the following code

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'}
```

Taking care of these two things fixed the error for me.
If in your case you have done anything else, then please share your code so that I can point to the cause of the error.

Comment: I'm not using gradle, I'm using intellij idea and i added all these lib to my project and set as dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I had the save error. After half of an hour I discovered, that recyclerview was not marked as "Library module" in project structure. This setting solved the problem

Comment: These sort of answers do not help anyone. Try to explain things in detail. Anyone seeing this now would have to go and google how to mark recyclerview in project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error today.
I Opened my project structure -> Modules.
Expand the module and select the Android option.
Set the support libraries modules as "Library Module" then it worked

I hope it helps
[Project Structure screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt4xX.png)

Answer (score -1):

After hours of battling this (and trying literally every solution online, what worked for me was:

1. Close AndroidStudio
2. Push project to remote
3. Delete project from local
4. Clone project again and run

Somehow, the local project got "corrupted"